# Entity class String[] vs List<String>

Tags: java, hibernate

I have concern about what type of attribute best for use in Entity class. In my problem I have string attribute to persist.

I want to know what is best option to use from following ways and their pros and cons.

```
String[] attribute;

List<String> attribute;
```

Thank you

Comment: any idea what implementation of List interface you're going to use?

Comment: Since when has Hibernate done JDO ?? It doesn't, so removed JDO tag

Answer (score 6):

If you have one string to presist, use a basic `String` field. If you have a fixed number of strings use `String[]`. If you don't know how many strings you may have, use `List<String>`.
But, I think the `List<String>` is usually preferable over `String[]`

Answer (score 3):

I would go for `List<?>`, because it is more natural for hibernate to work with a collection then fixed list (array). In other words with list you have more flexibility, because you can choose between several implementation of it. That give you flexible and easy to mange code.

But the final decision, for you is how would you use that object.

- Do the order of elements is important ?
- Do the amount of elements change often ?
- Do you perform lot of operations on it ?

I prefer working with Collection, because there exists plenty of tool where arrays should be transformed to collection to have some advantages, for example common.collections.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your needs. String [] will always be **fixed size**, but it's faster than Lists. If your stored variables are always the same count, and you consider performance, use String[].

If you don't expect huge amounts of Strings, better is to use Lists. Lists are **resizable**, and are part of Collections.
Lists are flexible. For example if you need synchronization over an *ArrayList* you can simply use:

```
Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
```

Using the *List* interfaces gives you the opportunity to switch easily to different implementation.

In the end, you can always obtain Array from *ArrayList*, using the `toArray()` method, for example to obtain faster processing times for certain operations.
*ArrayLists* offer random access to elements, at a cost of slower insertion and deletion of  elements in the middle of the list. In this case you should consider using *LinkedList* implementation of the *List* interface.

Comment: ArrayList is just as fast as an array, since it is a random access collection backed by an array.

Comment: yeah, but when you're changing size, you need time for relocation of elements. Fixed array size don't need that.

Comment: Yes, true, but if you know the size of your collection before creation you don't have to reallocate it. :) So for fixed size collections ArrayList may also be a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

In String[] attribute;
it would have fixed memory size and in List attribute;
its an arraylist of type string. You can add any number of strings to it using add method for arraylist object.

Comment: String[] is and array. In the List is also used an array but we do not have to declare the size of it.

Comment: Not true. You can store any number of strings in an array, but it's not dynamic, you have to 'reallocate' it if you need more than specified.

Answer (score 2):

String[] would have a fixed size when initialized and so would have a fixed memory size even if the items are not present in the array.

List would grow/shrink its size and thus its memory utilization, as the elements of type String are added/removed from the list.

Suggestions would be to use List in case you want to add/remove the items on need basis and, dont have a requirement of a fixed size array.